# How can i achieve this type of gradient in each cell?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitableview, cagradientlayer

[image]

How can i achieve the gradient below each cell ?

Comment: What did you try yourself to solve this requirement? Just asking for code is frowned up and might get your question down voted. Also post you attempts where your trued to solve this issue yourself.

Comment: for objective C or swift ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
class func addGradientInView(_ view : UIImageView , Color1 : UIColor , color2 : UIColor , cornerRadius : CGFloat, width : CGFloat) -> CAGradientLayer
    {
        view.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        view.layer.layoutSublayers()
        let labelGradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        labelGradient.masksToBounds = true
        labelGradient.frame = view.bounds
        labelGradient.frame.size.width = width
        labelGradient.frame.size.height = width
        labelGradient.colors = [(Color1.cgColor as AnyObject), (color2.cgColor as AnyObject)]
        view.layer.insertSublayer(labelGradient, at: 0)
        return labelGradient
    }
```

To call the above method:

```
addGradientInView(icon_Veges, Color1: darkGray_MaxAlpha,
                                                 color2:darkGray_MinAlpha,
                                                 cornerRadius: 0.0,
                                                 width:width)

Suppose:  let darkGray_MaxAlpha = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 0.1)
          let darkGray_MinAlpha = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6)
```

Note: Put view, color 1, color 2, width according to your need.

Comment: Brother did you convert this code in objective c ? because i need it so

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and subview the items you wanted like Name, Place etc.

Then initialise an object of CAGradientLayer and set colors, locations and frame. Then sublayer the object to UIView.

Following is the code snippet I suggest.

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0).CGColor,UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3).CGColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.1,1.0]
    gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds
    gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```